# Fetching Job metadata and publishing logs - driver or executor

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, hbase

We are building our data pipeline in pyspark and the first step is to fetch metadata (for each dataset) which is stored in HBase.  Also we have a couple of steps in the pipeline and are publishing our logs in the form of Kafka events.

1. Do we use the *hbase-python* api in the driver to fetch the metadata or use *spark.read.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")* - which is more efficient.
2. For publishing log messages to kafka, do we use a standard python-kafka producer in the driver or use the *df.write.format("kafka")* - does one of the approaches have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use Spark's supported formats rather than include standalone Python libraries in your applications.

This way, there will be no issues with serialization in Py4j between Spark executors.

You will also stay within SparkSQL dataframe formats, and should therefore be able to reduce code necessary to use HBase and Kafka from Spark methods.